# Rprop implementation

Tags: c#, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to implement rprop by using my old backprop code as a basis. I'm working on a perceptron with one hidden layer. Rprop algorithm is fairly simple, but I haven't figured all things out. This is my code:

```
for (j = 1; j <= nnh; j++)
{
    network.input2[j] = network.w12[0][j];
    for (i = 1; i <= nni; i++)
        network.input2[j] += network.input[i] * network.w12[i][j];

     network.output2[j] = (float)(1.0 / (1.0 + Math.Pow(Math.E, beta * -network.input2[j])));
}

for (k = 1; k <= nno; k++)
{
    network.input3[k] = network.w23[0][k];
    for (j = 1; j <= nnh; j++)
        network.input3[k] += network.output2[j] * network.w23[j][k];

     network.output[k] = (float)(1.0 / (1.0 + Math.Pow(Math.E, beta * -network.input3[k])));

    error += (float)(0.5 * (t[k - 1] - network.output[k]) * (t[k - 1] - network.output[k]));
    derivativeO[k] = (float)(t[k - 1] - network.output[k]) * network.output[k] * (1 - network.output[k]);
}

for (j = 1; j <= nnh; j++)
{
    saw[j] = 0;
    for (k = 1; k <= nno; k++)
        saw[j] += derivativeO[k] * network.output2[j];

    derivativeH[j] = saw[j] * network.output2[j] * (1 - network.output2[j]);
}

for (j = 1; j <= nnh; j++)//number of neurons in hidden layer
{
    for (i = 1; i <= nni; i++)//number of inputs
    {
        network.gradientH[i][j] = network.input[i] * derivativeH[j];

        if (network.gradientH[i][j] * network.gradientHPrev[i][j] > 0)
        {
            network.deltaH[i][j] = Math.Min(network.deltaH[i][j] * npos, dmax);
            network.w12d[i][j] = -Math.Sign(network.gradientH[i][j]) * network.deltaH[i][j];
            network.w12[i][j] += network.w12d[i][j];
            network.gradientHPrev[i][j] = network.gradientH[i][j];
        }
        else if (network.gradientH[i][j] * network.gradientHPrev[i][j] < 0)
        {
            network.deltaH[i][j] = Math.Max(network.deltaH[i][j] * nneg, dmin);
            network.gradientHPrev[i][j] = 0;
        }
        else if (network.gradientH[i][j] * network.gradientHPrev[i][j] == 0)
        {
            network.w12d[i][j] = -Math.Sign(network.gradientH[i][j]) * network.deltaH[i][j];
            network.w12[i][j] += network.w12d[i][j];
            network.gradientHPrev[i][j] = network.gradientH[i][j];
        }
    }
}

for (k = 1; k <= nno; k++)//number of outputs
{
    for (j = 1; j <= nnh; j++)//number of neurons in hidden layer
    {
        network.gradientO[j][k] = network.output2[j] * derivativeO[k];

        if (network.gradientOPrev[j][k] * network.gradientO[j][k] > 0)
        {
            network.deltaO[j][k] = Math.Min(network.deltaO[j][k] * npos, dmax);
            network.w23d[j][k] = -Math.Sign(network.gradientO[j][k]) * network.deltaO[j][k];
            network.w23[j][k] += network.w23d[j][k];
            network.gradientOPrev[j][k] = network.gradientO[j][k];
        }
        else if (network.gradientOPrev[j][k] * network.gradientO[j][k] < 0)
        {
            network.deltaO[j][k] = Math.Max(network.deltaO[j][k] * nneg, dmin);
            network.gradientOPrev[j][k] = 0;
        }
        else if (network.gradientOPrev[j][k] * network.gradientO[j][k] == 0)
        {
            network.w23d[j][k] = -Math.Sign(network.gradientO[j][k]) * network.deltaO[j][k];
            network.w23[j][k] += network.w23d[j][k];
            network.gradientOPrev[j][k] = network.gradientO[j][k];
        }
    }
}
```

The first three for loops are the same one I used in the backprop. That part of the code works fine. The problem arises during the weight update. I don't now if I'm calculating partial derivatives properly. Network sometimes converges and sometimes it's just behaving randomly. I think that I got everything else correct. Any thoughts?

For loops start from 1 because in previous backprop implementation bias values were stored first elements of weight matrices. This is previous backprop weight update implementation that works fine, maybe it will make some things clearer:

```
for (j = 1; j <= nnh; j++)
{
    network.w12d[0][j] = learningRate * derivativeH[j] + momentum * network.w12d[0][j];
    network.w12[0][j] += network.w12d[0][j];
    for (i = 1; i <= nni; i++)
    {
        network.w12d[i][j] = learningRate * network.input[i] * derivativeH[j] + momentum * network.w12d[i][j];
        network.w12[i][j] += network.w12d[i][j];
    }
}
for (k = 1; k <= nno; k++)
{
    network.w23d[0][k] = learningRate * derivativeO[k] + momentum * network.w23d[0][k];
    network.w23[0][k] += network.w23d[0][k];
    for (j = 1; j <= nnh; j++)
    {
        network.w23d[j][k] = learningRate * network.output2[j] * derivativeO[k] + momentum * network.w23d[j][k];
        network.w23[j][k] += network.w23d[j][k];
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the initial step size for `network.deltaO` and `network.deltaH`, as well as `npos` and `nneg`? I've found that if these values are "too large" (depends on the problem unfortunately) then this algorithm can behave erratically. (FWIW I don't see any problems in the code.)

Answer (score 0):

The Encog RPROP implementation works. It is MIT licensed. Take a look at their implementation here for comparison:

https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core/blob/master/encog-core-cs/Neural/Networks/Training/Propagation/Resilient/ResilientPropagation.cs